# Integrate Sharepoint and CRM 2016 on-premise

Tags: sharepoint, dynamics-crm-2016, sharepoint-2016

We have Dynamics CRM 2016 on-premise and Sharepoint 2016 on-premise. 
We'd like to configure the server-side-integration of the two products.

Several consultancies failed to setup the system. 
Now they claim that this integration is not supported (yet). 
I've found no documentation whether it is supported or not.

Question: Is it possible to integrate the two 2016 versions of the products? Did someone already do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the MSDN, CRM 2016 on-premise to SharePoint 2016 on-premise, server side integration is supported.

[Important considerations for server-based SharePoint integration](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn792527.aspx)

> Applies To: Dynamics 365 (online), Dynamics 365 (on-premises),
>   **Dynamics CRM 2016**, Dynamics CRM Online
>
> **Server-based SharePoint integration**
>
> Can connect:
>
> - Dynamics 365 (online) with SharePoint Online if the SharePoint site    is under the same Office 365 tenant as Dynamics 365 (online).
> - Dynamics 365 (online) with SharePoint on-premises.
> - Dynamics 365 on-premises with SharePoint Online.
> - **Dynamics 365 on-premises with SharePoint Server (on premises).**

Comment: And is Dynamics 365 on-premises the same as Dynamics CRM 2016 on-premises

Comment: @Sparhawk, I think so, its an update to 2016 as far as I know.

Comment: Our IT consultant retried and indeed: It does work. Sadly, I can't really put down why it didn't work before.

Answer (score 0):

We integrated CRM 2016 and SharePoint 2016, both on-premises. However, we have troubles showing custom columns added to SP document library in CRM. The system columns Name, Title, Modified, etc come through no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Microsoft Dynamics 2016 (on Prem) is compatible with SharePoint 2016 (on prem). But only for Server-based Integration. Below is the reference:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/3124955/compatibility-with-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2016